# Difference between paradigm and example

Tags: meaning, word-usage, synonyms

Can someone give me a perfect sentence which clearly shows the difference between paradigm and example?

Have read about it in the below site.
 https://wikidiff.com/paradigm/example

As nouns the difference between paradigm and example is that paradigm is an example serving as a model or pattern; a template while example is something that is representative of all such things in a group.  Suppose if I say Bill Gates is the world's richest person and I can refer him as a paradigm and say to my son , you should become like Bill Gates.!? And I can refer to top richest men as examples and ask my son to become like them. Is that even valid.!?

Comment: Welcome to ELU! Could you share the research you have done, and what you have come up with already?

Comment: Hi Marcello, have read the below in a site " https://wikidiff.com/paradigm/example " . As nouns the difference between paradigm and example

 is that paradigm is an example serving as a model or pattern; a template while example is something that is representative of all such things in a group.  Suppose if I say Bill Gates is the world's richest person and I can refer him as a paradigm and say to my son , you should become like Bill Gates.!? And I can refer to top richest men as examples and ask my son to become like them. Is that even valid.!?

Comment: you can [edit](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/423857/edit) in that information to the original post, so it doesn't get lost in the comments

Answer (score 1):

The [truncated icosohedron](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_icosahedron) is the paradigm for the majority of soccer ball designs, but examples can be found that use [different geometries](https://www.adidas.com/us/fifa-world-cup-glider-ball/CE8097.html).

Comment: In a way you might think so.  But no (fully inflated) soccer ball is in fact that shape.   And I do not think Bill Gates is the paradigm of private wealth.  Or if he is, it is because his name is the most commonly used name associated with super-wealth.  Once upon a time, it was Rockefeller, and before him Croesus.  In the same way, the paradigm case of an evil dictator is probably still (at least in the West) Hitler.   The modern paradigm case of a pacifist is probably still  Ghandi.   Ironically, the word ‘exemplar’ has a similar range of application to ‘paradigm’.